# `fontsize` results in extra leading vertical space when passed as a KOMAoptions setting vs. when passed as a class option

Tags: fontsize, koma-script

Consider the following LaTeX document:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=5pt]{scrartcl}
%\KOMAoptions{fontsize=5pt}
\usepackage[nohead,top=0pt]{geometry}
\begin{document}
Hello, world!
\end{document}
```

This gets pdf-rendered as follows (I only show the part of the pdf that is of interest, namely the top edge of the page):

[image: <code>fontsize</code> as a class option]

Notice how the text is flush against the top edge of the page, as expected given the `geometry` setting `top=0pt`.

Now consider a variation on the above document resulting from deleting the class option `[fontsize=5pt]`, and un-commenting the `\KOMAoptions{fontsize=5pt}` command:

[image: <code>fontsize</code> as a KOMAoptions setting]

Observe that now there's a vertical gap between the page's top edge and the text.

How come?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scrartcl` loads internally the package typearea. And typearea sets some length to values which depend on the font size. In your case `\topskip` has a value of 5pt when you set the fontsize in the class options and 11pt if you change the font size later.

You can force typearea to set all the values again with the command `\recalctypearea`:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\KOMAoptions{fontsize=5pt}
\recalctypearea
\usepackage[nohead,top=0pt]{geometry}
\begin{document}
Hello, world!
\end{document}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60300/discussion-on-answer-by-ulrike-fischer-fontsize-results-in-extra-leading-verti).

Comment: I've removed the checkmark, because the discussion implies that your answer is not quite correct, as it seems (as demonstrated by esdd) that the problem can be reproduced in the absence of `typearea`.

Comment: @EvanAad: Your question was why it makes a difference if the `fontsize` option is used in the class options or later. And this is due to typearea. If you load typearea *and* set the fontsize early enough then typearea changes the \topskip to 5pt, in all (allmost) other cases it remains at its default value. One example of the "other cases" is esdd's example, another is your own example with `\KOMAoptions`.

Comment: I see. OK, I've restored your checkmark. Thanks.